# Submenú con AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Me pidieron hacer un sub-menú en una página, pero revisando vi que el menú está hecho con AngularJS y nunca he trabajado con Angular. Si me podrían ayudar con un ejemplo o con algún tutorial, los que he encontrado son diferentes con respecto a como está el código.

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">   
      <div  ng-controller="MenuCtrl" ng-bind-html="Menu"></div> 
  </div><!-- /navbar-collapse -->
```

Y este es el JS/ANGULAR

```
    angular.module('AppMenus', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
       $scope.Menu = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">';
     /*$scope.Menu += '<li><a class="menu active" href="index.html" target="_self">HOME</a></li>';*/
       $scope.Menu += '<li><a class="menu" href="about.html" target="_self">SOMOS</a></li>';
       $scope.Menu += '<li><a class="menu" href="speciality.html" target="_self">ESPECIALIDADES</a></li>';
       $scope.Menu += '<li><a class="menu" href="stay.html" target="_self">STAY ACTIVE</a></li>';
       $scope.Menu += '<li><a class="menu" href="testimonio.html" target="_self">TESTIMONIOS</a></li>';
       $scope.Menu +='<li><a class="menu" href="benefity.html" target="_self">BENEFICIOS</a></li>';
       $scope.Menu += ' <li><a class="menu" href="contact.html" target="_self">CONTACTO</a></li>';
       $scope.Menu += '<li><a class="menu" href="http://www.cifo.com.mx/en/" target="_self"><img src="img/United-States-of-Americ-icon.png" alt=""></a></li>';

      $scope.Menu += '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que tengo entendido, el submenu es simplemente un ul dentro de un li

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Sottotitolo 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sottotitolo 2</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sottotitolo 3 <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Entonces solo debes concatenar ese ul dentro del li

```
$scope.Menu += '<li> <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nuovo sottotitolo 2</a></li>            
    </ul> </li>';
```

Espero te sirva, saludos...